# Is there a way to determine if EmailMessage has reply

Tags: trigger, email, email-template, email2case

I'm after finding a way to know if a EmailMessage object has a reply?

I have tried to use Trigger `after insert` but I do not see its picking.
Any other better way?

when the user response to email-to-case... I just need to know when/if the user has a reply

```
trigger hasReply on EmailMessage (before insert, after insert, after delete, after update) 
{
   if(trigger.isInsert) {    
      system.debug('got reply?');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) you can look for ReplyToEmailMessageId field .This field has a value if the message is a reply and also if there is a reply to your case there will be a single record in SFDC DB for EmailMessage record with ParentId field as CaseId .

You can use these fields to query back from DB or check the field values to find whether these are reply .